# Weird behavior when refreshing an Android fragment's view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, refresh

I am having hard time doing a task which is supposed to be easy. I am not sure whether it is because of the Android platform's bad design or if I am missing something. I simply would like to refresh a fragment's view on resume. Here are the details:

I have two activities, a SplashActivity which retrieves data from a server (using a AsyncTask) and passes the data to my MainActivity. In my MainActivity, I get this data and pass it to a fragment named SummaryFragment. I have a few fragments and a navigation drawer (in my MainActivity). The first visible fragment is the SummaryFragment which reads the data passed to it from the MainActivity and consequently draws a graph.

When the app starts, there might be no active Internet connection, in that case, in my summary fragment I ask the user to enable WiFi. What I want to do is to refresh this SummaryFragment's view after the user comes back to the app after enabling WiFi. What I do right now is that in the onResume() of my MainActivity, I check if the SummaryFragment in visible, and if so, I start the SplashActivity again (and close the current activity). SplashActivity must fetches the data (like it does when the app starts) and start the MainActivity (fed with the fetched data) which loads the summary fragment and shows the graph.

The problem is that it **takes a considerably long time (30-40 seconds)** after the app is resumed to go from the SplashActivity to the MainActivity and show the graph (meanwhile the users sees the splash screen), whereas when the app starts it takes 1-2 seconds to do so. Before using the current solution (redirecting user to the SplashActivity), in MainActivity.onResume() I tried using the same AsyncTask class that I am using in the SplashScreen to fetch the data and show the summary fragment afterwards, but the result is the same, there is a significant delay.

The following code is my MainActivity's onResume():

```
Fragment fragment = getVisibleFragment();
if (fragment instanceof SummaryFragment) {
    Intent intentSplashActvity = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "about to start the splash activity");
    startActivity(intentSplashActvity);
    // close current activity
    finish();
    super.onResume();
    return;
}
super.onResume();
```

The SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        new PrefetchData(this).execute();
    }       
}
```

The PrefetchData:

```
public class PrefetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String serverResponseJson = null;
    private String data1 = null,
                   data2 = null,
                   data3 = null;

    private SplashActivity mSplashActivity = null;
    private MainActivity mMainActivity;

    public PrefetchData(Activity sourceActivity){
        if (sourceActivity.getClass() == SplashActivity.class) {
            mSplashActivity = (SplashActivity) sourceActivity;
        } 
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        try {
            if (CaratApplication.isInternetAvailable()) {
                serverResponseJson = jsonParser
                        .getJSONFromUrl("http://aURL");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("SplashActivity", e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
        if (serverResponseJson != null && serverResponseJson != "") {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONObject(serverResponseJson).getJSONArray("arrayName");

                // Using Java reflections to set fields by passing their name to a method
                try {
                    setFieldsFromJson(jsonArray, 0, "data1");
                    setFieldsFromJson(jsonArray, 1, "data2");
                    setFieldsFromJson(jsonArray, 2, "data3");
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (mSplashActivity != null) {
            Intent intentMainActvity = new Intent(mSplashActivity, MainActivity.class);

            if (gotDataSuccessfully()) {
                intentMainActvity.putExtra("data1", data1);
                intentMainActvity.putExtra("data2", data2);
                intentMainActvity.putExtra("data3", data3);
            } else {
                intentMainActvity.putExtra("data1", Constants.DATA_NOT_AVAIABLE);
                intentMainActvity.putExtra("data2", Constants.DATA_NOT_AVAIABLE);
                intentMainActvity.putExtra("data3", Constants.DATA_NOT_AVAIABLE);
            }

            mSplashActivity.startActivity(intentMainActvity);

            mSplashActivity.finish();
        } 
    }
}
```

In MainActivity, upon selection of the "summary" entry in the navigation drawer, I initialize the SummaryFragment, and then replace it using a fragment transaction (**replaceFragment(mSummaryFragment, mSummaryFragmentLabel)**). Here is the method I use to initialize the summary fragment:

```
private void initSummaryFragment() {
    if (mData1 == 0 && mData2 == 0 && mData3 == 0) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String data1 = intent.getStringExtra("data1");
        String data2 = intent.getStringExtra("data2"); 
        String data3 = intent.getStringExtra("data3");

        boolean isDataAvaiable = !data1.equals(Constants.DATA_NOT_AVAIABLE)
                && !data2.equals(Constants.DATA_NOT_AVAIABLE) && !data3.equals(Constants.DATA_NOT_AVAIABLE);
        if (isDataAvaiable) {
            mData1 = Integer.parseInt(data1);
            mData2 = Integer.parseInt(data2);
            mData3 = Integer.parseInt(data3);
        } 
    }

    mSummaryFragment = new SummaryFragment();
    mArgs = new Bundle();       
    mArgs.putInt("data1", mData1);
    mArgs.putInt("data2", mData2);
    mArgs.putInt("data3", mData3);      
    mSummaryFragment.setArguments(mArgs);
    mSummaryFragmentLabel = getString(R.string.summary);
}
```

The SummaryFragment can now retrieve the data it needs from the bundle passed to it.

Comment: Why did somebody down-vote the question? I assume just randomly down-voting questions without giving explanations is very odd and impolite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the (rather) undocumented behavior of Android's AsyncTask. An AsyncTask **does not run in a separate thread**, it runs in a thread that is shared with other AsyncTasks, so if you have other AsyncTasks (or even a plain thread), if they start running before your current AsyncTask, this AsyncTask **waits** for them to complete their action. I explicitly specified that I would like my AsyncTask to run in a separate thread, and this reduced the delay from about 20-25 seconds to 3-4 seconds for fetching a JSON object (I have other network access calls in progress in parallel). I run the following code as part of my preInitFragments() method in onCreate() method of my main activity.

```
// The following PrefetchData class is of type AsyncTask<void, void, void>. I moved this class from a stand-alone class to an inner class inside my main activity for easier refreshing of my fragment.
PrefetchData prefetchData = new PrefetchData();
// run this asyncTask in a new thread [from the thread pool] (run in parallel to other asyncTasks)
// (do not wait for them to finish, it takes a long time)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    prefetchData.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
 else
     prefetchData.execute();
```

After this I call my method initSummaryFragment(). Please note that in my AsyncTask, in doInBackGround(), I set the two fields (mField1 and mField2) you see below (I used to pass them as a bundle to the summary screen, but that way would cause a problem when you were just detaching and attaching the fragment (to refresh its view) without passing a bundle to your fragment). In the onPostExecute() of my asyncTask, I invoke my method refreshSummaryFragment():

```
private boolean isStatsDataAvailable() {
    return mWellbehaved != 0 && mHogs != 0 && mBugs != 0;
}

private void initSummaryFragment() {        
    if (! isStatsDataAvailable()) { 
        mSummaryFragment = new SummaryFragment();
    }           
    mSummaryFragmentLabel = "Summary";
}
```

For refreshing my summary fragment, I simply detach, and attach my summary fragment, and then commit the pending fragment transaction:

```
public void refreshSummaryFragment() {
    if (isStatsDataAvailable()) { // blank summary fragment already attached. detach and attach to refresh

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // init the fragment (for later use when user selects an item from the navigation drawer)               
        mSummaryFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Summary"); 

        FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        // refresh the summary fragment:
        fragTransaction.detach(mSummaryFragment);
        fragTransaction.attach(mSummaryFragment);
        fragTransaction.commit();
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "refreshSummaryFragment(): stats data not avaiable!");
    }
}
```